# Получить абсолютный путь в Slim 4 + Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim, slim4

Всем привет! Решил переехать на Slim Framework 4. Возникла проблема. В twig-шаблоне нужно получить полный путь сайта, например, http://example.com.
Собственно, возникла проблема, что не знаю, как это можно сделать.
Увидел в slim-twig такой фрагмент кода:

```
$scheme = $uri->getScheme();
$authority = $uri->getAuthority();
$protocol = ($scheme ? $scheme . ':' : '') . ($authority ? '//' . $authority : '');
```

Где $protocol - как раз содержится нужный мне http://example.com.
Теперь думаю, как его можно применить в решении моей задачи.
Возможно, стоит создать какой-нибудь middleware.

Если есть хорошее элегантное решение, подскажите, пожалуйста.
P.S.: Конечно, можно использовать просто захардкоженый полный путь сайта, но, думаю, что есть более хорошие варианты.

Comment: А как Вы сейчас делаете?

Answer (score 0):

Я создал расширение для twig

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Support\Twig;

use Closure;
use Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface;
use Slim\Interfaces\RouteParserInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

final class RouteExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

    /**
     * @var RouteParserInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var UriInterface
     */
    private $uri;

    public function __construct(RouteParserInterface $router, UriInterface $uri)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->setUri($uri);
    }

    public funstion setUri(UriInterface $uri)
    {
        $this->uri = $uri;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return  [
            new TwigFunction('route', Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'route'])),
        ];
    }

    private function route(string $route, array $params = [], array $query = [], bool $absolute = false): string
    {
        if ($absolute) {
            $this->router->fullUrlFor($this->uri, $route, $params, $query);
        }
        return $this->router->urlFor($route, $params, $query);
    }
}
```

И в контейнере при билдинге twig добавляю это расширение (тут уже реализация от конкретного контейнера зависит)

```php
$options = [
    'cache' => $container->get('dir.cache.twig'),
];
$twig = new Environment(
    $container->get(Twig\Loader\LoaderInterface::class),
    $options
);
$twig->addExtension($container->get(App\Support\Twig\RouteExtension::class));
```

Т.к. у меня приложение работает на нескольких доменах, в контейнере я создаю экземпляр с объектом Uri из конфигурации (дефолтный), а в миддлваре передаю объект из запроса:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Middleware;

use App\Support\Twig\RouteExtension;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

final class TwigRouteExtensionMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{

    /**
     * @var RouteExtension
     */
    private $extension;

    public function __construct(RouteExtension $extension)
    {
        $this->extension = $extension;
    }

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        $this->extension->setUri($request->getUri());
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
```

И в шаблонах строю урл по роутингу

```
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
<a href="{{ route('privacy_policy', {}, {}, true) }}">Privacy Policy</a>
{% endblock %}
```